# if with mysql results in syntax error

Tags: mysql, if-statement, syntax

I need to use a if statment in my mysql trigger. It looks like that:

```
set @countentry = (SELECT count(id) as `id` FROM `tsc_page_have_wildcard` where idwildcard=1 and idpage=5);
IF  @countentry <> 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO `tsc_page_have_wildcard` (`idpage`, `idwildcard`) VALUES (@pageid, NEW.id);
END IF
```

By executing the trigger i get: 
 Error Code: 1064. You have an error

> in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF  @countentry <> 0
>   THEN
>
> ```
>         INSERT INTO `tsc_page_have_wildcard` (`i' at line 1
> ```
>
> The table struct is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tsc_page_have_wildcard` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `idpage` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idwildcard` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `idpage` (`idpage`,`idwildcard`),
  KEY `idwildcard` (`idwildcard`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

ALTER TABLE `tsc_page_have_wildcard`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tsc_page_have_wildcard_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idpage`) REFERENCES `tsc_page` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tsc_page_have_wildcard_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`idwildcard`) REFERENCES `tsc_wildcard` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

INSERT INTO `tsc_page_have_wildcard` (`id`, `idpage`, `idwildcard`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2),
(3, 1, 3),
(4, 1, 4),
(5, 1, 5),
(6, 41, 4),
(7, 41, 5);
```

Does anyone know why this if statment isnt working in my trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */ TRIGGER `win` AFTER INSERT 
ON `tsc_page_have_wildcard` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  SET @countentry = 
  (SELECT 
    COUNT(id) AS `id` 
  FROM
    `tsc_page_have_wildcard` 
  WHERE idwildcard = 1 
    AND idpage = 5) ;
  IF @countentry <> 0 
  THEN 
  INSERT INTO `tsc_page_have_wildcard` (`idpage`, `idwildcard`) 
  VALUES
    (@pageid, NEW.id) ;
  END IF ;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Semi-colon(;) after END IF :-)